# Result consisted of more than one row when executing linq query against mysql database?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When I run the following query in VS2008 with EF 3.5, I get the error:

`Result consisted of more than one row`

```
var drivers = _context.Persons
                          .Where(x => x.client == client)
                          .Select(x => new { x.first_name, 
                                             x.middle_name, 
                                             x.last_name, 
                                             x.person_no})
                          .ToList();
```

I am not sure what could cause this error.  When I run it outside VS, for example, I ran it in Linpad and it worked fine.

I have 5 columns in the database: `first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`, `person_no`, and `order_no`.

When I execute the above query with `order_no` as null, it works, but when I put data in `order_no`, it fails with the error and I am not even bringing back `order_no`, so it is confusing me.

Comment: can a `Person` have more than one `client`?

Comment: @paul - Yes they can. A Person can belong to many clients.

Comment: When I execute this part, it hits the exception.

Comment: Your code looks fine so it seems something is missing with your question.
Can you post all the surrounding relevant code?

Comment: @graumanoz - I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.  I had sql executing behind the scenes, a function in this case that would get a name based on the person_no and this function was returning multiple rows because person_no is not unique.  So I have something like this:

```
select 
    fnName(person_no),
    first_name,
    middle_name,
    last_name,
    person_no,
from
    Persons
```

In the above, `fnName` returns more than one row.